# I need a PHP script to decrypt the RSA encrypted string generated by

Tags: php, javascript, cryptography

I need a PHP script to decrypt the RSA encrypted string generated by this JavaScript library - http://ohdave.com/rsa/

I'm either missing something or I don't know, but I don't remember what was the last thing I looked for so long after and did not find :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've asked this question; however I've found in meantime an simple way to achieve what I was asking above: http://www.jcryption.org/

Good luck to everyone,
titel

Answer (score 2):

I dunno about you, but i do quick google and found this match:

http://www.sematopia.com/?p=275
http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/4121.html
[[RSA encryption/decryption compatible with Javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610048/rsa-encryption-decryption-compatible-with-javascript-and-php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610048/rsa-encryption-decryption-compatible-with-javascript-and-php)

Comment: That PHPClasses class is unpadded textbook RSA with MD5 signatures, which are in turn verified insecurely. Please avoid it.