# RSA Encrypt and Decrypt Strings on Android

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

I'm reading pages and pages since weeks but I cannot find a solution.
I want "only" to:

1. Make my own public and private keys to encrypt and decrypt strings between my PHP website and Android application (like on http://www.example-code.com/android/rsa_generateKey.asp but how can I store and use the generated keys?)
2. Encrypt a string on my application
3. Decrypt the string from my website
4. Encrypt a string on my website
5. Decrypt the string from my application

I've just found a class that does simply this job ( http://www.example-code.com/android/rsa_encryptStrings.asp ) but it is not free, and to make it work on PHP I should install a PHP extension but I can't on my web hosting.

Is there something similar? I'm studying a lot but I don't know why I don't understand how to do it in different ways.

Probably something similar to

[RSA Android Encrypt / RSA PHP Decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331684)

could help but it is not the complete source code.

Please give me some real working examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt and Decrypt text with RSA in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484246/encrypt-and-decrypt-text-with-rsa-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

this should do it.

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption_2.shtml

It's not an android question, much more Java.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try asap... but how can i 3. decrypt the string from my website (based on PHP)? Do you think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770830/i-need-a-php-script-to-decrypt-the-rsa-encrypted-string-generated-by could be what i need? Thanks again! ;)

Comment: Thanks, it works but i was looking for something like "license3j" because it has all expiration date/release/etc. management tool and it could be really what i need. Unfortunately it is not compatible with Android. Do you know any "Licence Management" tool compatible with Android? I don't want to publish the application on Android Market. Thanks ;)