# Why the Javascript did not encrypt my form?

Tags: javascript, php, rsa, phpseclib

Javascript RSA Library is from https://github.com/ziyan/javascript-rsa

PHP RSA Library is from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Example is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10922491/5281854

My code (the browser still send the original text to the server):

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
session_start();
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo $_POST['password'];
    echo 1;
    $rsa->loadKey($_SESSION['privatekey']);
    echo $rsa->decrypt($_POST['password']);
    exit();
}
extract($rsa->createKey(4096));

$_SESSION['privatekey']=$privatekey;
$publickey=str_replace("\n", "\\\n", $publickey);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jsbn.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="rsa.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

    function encryptData(){

        //Don't forget to escape the lines:
        var pem = "<?php echo $publickey; ?>";
        var key = RSA.getPublicKey(pem);
        element=document.getElementById('password');
        element.value=RSA.encrypt(element.value, key);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method='POST' id='txtAuth' onsubmit='encryptData()'>
    <input type='text' name='username'/>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' placeholder="password"/>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

All the library files are correctly loaded. Can anyone tell me why the encryption does not work?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Actually no. I used alert() and found the javascript stopped when executing "RSA.encrypt(element.value, key)"

Comment: uhm.. are you sure the public key value is encoded correctly? I see that the RSA library expects it to be put in a specific format.

Comment: Is the `key` after `var key = RSA.getPublicKey(pem);` perhaps `false`? Can you give an example of the generated public key in PEM format? Please [edit] you question to include the missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried your code on my own local machine and ran into a few issues.

1. You're doing `str_replace("\n", "\\\n", $publickey)` - I had to do `str_replace("\r\n", "\\\n", $publickey)` or else I'd get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error in the javascript console.
2. Even after having done #1 I'm still getting a `Uncaught TypeError: this.toRadix is not a function` error. I'm using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ziyan/javascript-rsa/master/src/jsbn.js and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ziyan/javascript-rsa/master/src/rsa.js and I haven't really modified your code at all. Try it out for yourself: http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/so/

That said, looking at your rsa.js...  I still stand by my original statement that `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);` should work assuming that the javascript errors can be overcome. Unfortunately, since I can't get past them (and I'm not interested in fixing a piece of code that hasn't been updated in three years) I can't verify. Do you actually have a working example, yourself, that doesn't produce errors in the JS console?

Comment: Em... this does not work actually. I tried to copy the example (mentioned at the top) without changing it, it did not work, either.

Comment: @HowardLiu - I'm getting syntax and runtime errors with your javascript that are preventing me from testing the PHP side of it. I edited my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem.