# rsa decryption data from an encrypted data

Tags: encryption, rsa

I have tried many approaches to get the decryted data.  I have used the same public key and private key to encrypt the data as given in the link
 Please see the attached link.

[RSA encryption/decryption compatible with Javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610048/rsa-encryption-decryption-compatible-with-javascript-and-php)

Finally I got the encrpted data (I have used extjs for encrption).I need to get the decrypted data in java.
Please suggest me a solution to get the decrypted by using same keys or  solution to generate random keys for encrytion and decrytion

Comment: Lets see some code from your failing attempts